# Divide a List in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to divide a List to two parts.

I have a list 1 = List cardbank = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]

How can i create list2 and list3 from list 1 random ?

For example ;

List 2 be like = [3,6,7,8]
and
List 3 be like = [1,2,4,5]

This is my CardClass :

```
class CardClass {
  int deger;
  String tip;
  int id;

  CardClass(this.deger, this.tip, this.id);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ ${deger}, ${tip}}';
  }
}
```

and this is my list

```
class CardBrain {
  List<CardClass> cardbank = [
    CardClass(1, "for", 1),
    CardClass(2, "for", 2),
    CardClass(3, "for", 3),
  ];

  Random _random = new Random();
  int max = (cardbank.length / 2).floor(); //It says The instance member cant be accessed to initializer
  final anan = cardbank.length;
}
```

Comment: First, you cannot really add your code directly in the class definition as you are doing now. In Dart, all variables are defined in the class at the same time in an initialization phase. In next phase, the constructor code are running. So you cannot point to another variable in the class definition when declaring another variable since your other variable does not exists yet. This is different from Java.

Comment: So can you try show how you want your lists to be in `CardBrain`? Do you want three lists here or just the two split? Try show what you want you class to contain instead of what you are trying to do now. :)

Comment: I want just 2 list from 'cardbank' . I want to write a card game. Total :52 card , and the user get 26 random card. It's a game , maybe you know it. I add a class definition because every card has different value and picture. Did you understand what i mean ?

Comment: I pasted the code into a method. And problem solved :) . I cant really add my code directly in the class definition. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, so your problem is solved? If yes, please accept the answer you have found most helpful. :)

Comment: I did. Thank you. I feel embarrassed. I took your time. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it shorter like this:

```
void main() {
  final list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
  
  final list1Copy = list1.toList()..shuffle();
  final list2 = list1Copy.sublist(0, list1Copy.length ~/ 2);
  final list3 = list1Copy.sublist(list1Copy.length ~/ 2);

  print(list1); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  print(list2); // [4, 6, 8, 3]
  print(list3); // [5, 1, 7, 2]
}
```

You can skip the `list1Copy` if you don't care about `list1` being shuffled under the process.

Comment: Hi. I can't get the lenght of List. It says = "  The instance member cant be accessed initialized. " . Do you have an idea ?

Comment: This one is definitely much better.

Comment: @EmreVarol Can you show me how you have pasted my code into your solution? My example should work if you use it directly (e.g. use it with dartpad).

Comment: List<CardClass> cardbank = [
    CardClass(1, "maca", 1),
    CardClass(2, "maca", 2),
    CardClass(3, "maca", 3),]   and , final anan = cardbank.length; Its not working

Comment: @EmreVarol Are you trying to do this in a constructor?

Comment: Yes. Why ? İs it  not possible ?

Comment: @EmreVarol Well, you need to understand how variables are set when creating an object (it really happens in two steps). I think you need to make a small example of how your class looks so I can give the best solution for you.

Comment: Okey. I editted my question. Can you check

Answer (score 2):

You may try the code below : [Please see the answer by @julemand101 for a better solution]

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  List<String> list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
  List<String> list2 = [];
  List<String> list3 = [];

  Random _random = new Random();
  int max = (list1.length / 2).floor();
  for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    int nextInt = _random.nextInt(list1.length);
    list2.add(list1[nextInt]);
    list1.removeAt(nextInt);
  }
  list3 = List.from(list1);

  print(list2);
  print(list3);
}
```

Comment: Yup, seems like the best way to do so

Comment: Yes. Very helpful answer. Thank you. I click the useful button but it didn't work.

Comment: I have tested the code and can see it has a bug since `list2` will always contain `8` as the last element. So the random aspect is not really working as expected.

Comment: @julemand101 Thanks for letting me know, I fixed it now.

Comment: @julemand101 But your code is much better and it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I added a note in my answer to see your answer for a better solution.